# jQuery: click on <td> element having a <img> element as child

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I would like to make a jQuery snippet of code that clicks on a "next page" button on a certain webpage.

The html of the webpage is like:

```
<td>...things...</td>
<td>...things...</td>
<td>...things...</td>

<!-- next page button -->
<td align="left" class="LURDA0B-K-a-com-google-gwt-user-cellview-client-SimplePager-Style-button" style="vertical-align: middle;">
<img src="data:image/png;base64,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" width="19" height="19" class="gwt-Image" role="button" aria-label="Next page" aria-disabled="false">
</td>

<td>...things...</td>
<td>...things...</td>
<td>...things...</td>
```

The "next page" element is a  element having a  element has child and having an attribute-value pair `aria-label="Next page"`.

I have developed a snippet that (using the jQuery [`.html()`](https://api.jquery.com/html/) api) gets the html of the "next page" element

```
$('td').has('img[aria-label="Next page"]').html();
```

> ```
> '<img src="data:image/png;base64,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" width="19" height="19" class="gwt-Image" role="button" aria-label="Next page" aria-disabled="false">'
> ```

But for some reason, when I change the `.html()` part into `.click()`, like so

```
$('td').has('img[aria-label="Next page"]').click();
```

it does not click it, so that the webpage does not change to the next one.

What is wrong? How can I fix it?

```
$('img[aria-label="Next page"]').click();
```

does not work either.

Comment: Thanks mplungjan
 . `$('img[aria-label="Next page"]').click();` Not working. I updated the question.

Comment: are you sure you have an handler for the click event on the td element? because the criteria to reach that element is right and the way to trigger the click event also. I would use a better approach than img[aria-label] but that's beyond your question. Are you sure only one element gets returned from that selector? only one td having that img with that attribute?

Comment: Try it with `.trigger( "click" )` instead of `.click()`

Comment: from https://api.jquery.com/click/#click-handler - This method is a shortcut for .on( "click", handler ) in the first two variations, and .trigger( "click" ) in the third. - the third variation is .click(). So that's not the solution

Comment: @DiegoDeVita thanks for your attention.
- "Are you sure only one element gets returned from that selector?" Yes, when using the .html() method, it retruns only the html string of that "next page" element.
- "are you sure you have an handler for the click event on the td element?" No, is there a way to check it out?

Comment: Try: `$('img[aria-label="Next page"]')[0].click();`

Comment: @freedomn-m yes! It works, paste it as answer and I will flag it as correct!

Comment: They'll be more than a few duplicates...  just need to find a relevant one.   Glad it works.   Reason: jquery `.click()` only fires events that have been added via jquery.  If you have a native/vanilla javascript event, jquery doesn't fire it.

Comment: @freedomn-m thanks for saying that.. there are some details that we always forget and we re-invent the wheel each time burning the memory of the event until next time we'll hit our head on it

Answer (score 0):

you need to find where the event handler is attached.

The click bubbles

```js
$("tr").on("click",function(e) {
  console.log($(e.currentTarget).attr("id"), "clicked");
})

$("#row2 td").on("click",function(e) {
  console.log($(e.currentTarget).attr("id"), "clicked");
})

$("#row2 td img").on("click",function(e) {
  console.log($(e.currentTarget).attr("id"), "clicked");
})

console.log("clicking td")
$('td').has('img[aria-label="Next page"]').click();

console.log("clicking img")

$('img[aria-label="Next page"]').click();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr id="row1">
    <td>...things...</td>
    <td>...things...</td>
    <td>...things...</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row2">
    // next page button
    <td id="row2cell1" align="left" class="LURDA0B-K-a-com-google-gwt-user-cellview-client-SimplePager-Style-button" style="vertical-align: middle;">
      <img id="image" src="data:image/png;base64,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"
        width="19" height="19" class="gwt-Image" role="button" aria-label="Next page" aria-disabled="false">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```